# Node Js Puppeteer value is not defined in the function (page.evaluate)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am currently using Puppeteer (NodeJs). I use the page.evaluate function but unfortunately I get "token is not defined".
Code:

```
const token = tokenData.split("\n")[i]
page.evaluate(() => {
setInterval(() => {document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {location.reload();}, 2500);
})
```

When i try to console log token i get "token is not defined".
When i change the token var with the actual token it´s working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use variables declared in Node.js context inside function argument of `page.evaluate()`, but you can transfer their values via additional arguments:

```js
const token = tokenData.split("\n")[i];
page.evaluate((myToken) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`)
      .contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${myToken}"`
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(() => {location.reload();}, 2500);
}, token); // <- here is the transferring
```

Comment: I don't know if I misunderstood something about it, but when I now read token I get the error again that token is not defined. If I log myToken I get absolutely nothing out.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the whole situation. However, it is how the [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) works. Its function is recreated in the browsed context and has no access to Node.js context.